How to reduce the size of bundle apk in Android?
We have a native library (.so) which is about 2 MB for each Architecture('x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a’). Using this Native library we have written an SDK which is going to be integrated with Android App (distributed as 'aar' files).
In our sample app when integrated with the SDK and hosted on google play store, it shows the download size to be 14 MB (which is roughly correct if we have all the 4 native libraries inside the APK).
But each device support multiple architectures, this solution doesn’t work for us. Is there a way to make sure that Google play store picks up only one .so files as per the architecture so that it will significantly reducing the size of each APK?
We have tried the following in build.gradle:
android {     
    ...      // Configure the splits block     
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true // Enable ABI splits             
            reset() // Reset any previous configurations
            include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'mips' // Specify the ABIs you want to include             
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs         
        }
    }
}    

Explanation: enable true: Enables ABI splits. reset(): Clears any previous ABI configurations. include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'mips': Specifies the ABIs you want to include in your splits. universalApk false: Disables the creation of a universal APK that includes all ABIs.  But each device support multiple architectures, this solution doesn’t work for us.

That behavior is built into Google Play these days. You don't need to do anything.  (In the old days you would upload separate apk files per architecture, but that's been unnecessary for years)

Also you wouldn't want to do that in an aar file, as the people using the library need all those targets to make it work on emulators, and various devices (ok, maybe you can drop mips, that's a very rarely used one).  So your aar still wants to have everything

Some devices may support multiple architectures but that is only for compatibility, so as app developer you don't have to care about such devices. It only matter that one of the device architectures is also supported by your app. If the intersection between device and app has more than one architecture then Google Play will chose one arch on download.
